# Vue: data is not binding to props therefore not rendering BarChart using vue-D3-charts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

I would like render a simple bar chart.

I'm learning how to use D3 module for data visualisation by using `vue-d3-charts` within a component in my vue.js app.

I have created a bar-chart component and imported it into my app but it will not render the actual bar chart. When I use dev tools to inspect the bar I can see the associated div's and svg for the bar chart but the chart doesn't render onto the page.

This leads me to believe my data object is not being bound to my props to allow `D3BarChart` from `vue-D3-charts` module to render.

Module docs can be found here -> https://saigesp.github.io/vue-d3-charts/#/

My `BarChart` component which uses the props `config` and `datum`:

```
<template>
  <div class="bar-chart">
    <D3BarChart :config="chart_config" :datum="chart_data"></D3BarChart>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { D3BarChart } from "vue-d3-charts";

export default {
  name: "BarChart",
  components: { D3BarChart },
  props: ["config", "datum"],
  data() {
    return {
      chart_config: {
        key: "name",
        value: "total",
        color: { current: "#41B882" },
        transition: { ease: "easeBounceOut", duration: 1000 },
      },
      chart_data: [
        {
          iphone: 123,
          android: 208,
          when: "2019-08-01",
        },
        {
          iphone: 165,
          android: 201,
          when: "2019-09-01",
        },
      ],
    };
  },

};
</script>
```

My app.js :

```
<template>
  <main id="app">
    <bar-chart />

    <section class="products">
      <!-- A prop called product which takes the object product creasted in the for loop - in turn creating a prop that contains one product item from the products object-->
      <product-card
        v-for="product in products"
        :key="product.color"
        :productDataProp="product"
      />
    </section>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import ProductCard from "./components/ProductCard.vue";
// import BasicLineChart from "./components/BasicLineChart.vue";

import BarChart from "./components/BarChart.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    ProductCard,
    BarChart,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      products: [
        {
          title: "Nike Air Max",
          color: "green",
          bgtext: "NIKE",
          src: require("./assets/green-shoe.png"),
        },
        {
          title: "Nike flex",
          color: "blue",
          bgtext: "AIR",
          src: require("./assets/blue-shoe.png"),
        },
        {
          title: "Nike Roche Runs",
          color: "pink",
          bgtext: "MAX",
          src: require("./assets/pink-shoe.png"),
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: "montseratt", sans-serif;
}
main {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.products {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1280px;
  padding: 25;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

[image: Dev tools inspector]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made minor changes in BarChart.vue, and it is working. Can you try below:

Few issues that I found and fixed are:

1. div "bar-chart" width is too small, so it is not able to generate chart.
2. In "chart_config" key and values where incorrect acc. to your "chart_data".

BarChart.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="bar-chart" style="border:1px solid black; width:90%">
    <D3BarChart :config="chart_config" :datum="chart_data"></D3BarChart>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { D3BarChart } from 'vue-d3-charts';

export default {
  components: {
    D3BarChart,
  },
  data() {
    return {

      chart_data: [
        {
          iphone: 123,
          android: 208,
          when: "2019-08-01",
        },
        {
          iphone: 165,
          android: 201,
          when: "2019-09-01",
        }
      ],
      chart_config: {
        key: 'when',
        values: ['iphone','android'],
        color: { 
            default: '#222f3e',
            current: '#41B882'
        },
        transition: { ease: "easeBounceOut", duration: 1000 },
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Jay , this has solve an issue that I have been having for the past few days. Now I understand how it all works. 

So I didn't have to add the props like this `props: ["config", "datum"]` why is that?

Comment: You can add props like that but it is not used anywhere on this page. So I removed.